# moving big shed footings

Tags: shed, footings

i need to move a 16x20 shed back about 12', so half the shed will remain on existing footings. the current footings are all poured concrete. do i need to dig new footings or can half the shed just sit on concrete blocks on the dirt or even on 2'x2' concrete pads about 2" thick. i'm in central NJ
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a shed, concrete blocks should do fine. Hundreds of thousands of sheds and mobile homes across the US have proven that.

Answer (score 0):

Yea concrete blocks should be ok, but make sure that they are level with the existing footings, and also make sure that you compact the ground VERY well where these blocks will be sitting.